# JSFL: create AS file

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, jsfl

Is there a way to create and save .as file using JSFL?

I know that you can save and rename Fla documents, but what about .as classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found it: `outputPanel.save()` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_ExtendingFlash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7a03.html

`FLfile.write()` is good, too :)

Answer (score 0):

More beautiful thing is to use [FLfile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fa1.html) object. It provides more file manipulation stuff.